# How do I change the autoindent to 2 space in IPython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, auto-indent

I find that developing functions in IPython notebook allows me to work quickly. When I'm happy with the results I copy-paste to a file. The autoindent is 4 spaces, but the coding style for indentation at my company is 2 spaces. How do I change the autoindent to 2 spaces?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20197471/2870069) question and the options found [here](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html):
In your custom.js file (location depends on your OS) put

`IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.indentUnit = 2;`

On my machine the file is located in `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom`

### Update:

In IPython 3 the plain call does not work any more, thus it is required to place the setting within an appropriate event handler. A possible solution could look like

```css
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
    ],
    function(IPython, events) {
        events.on("app_initialized.NotebookApp",
            function () {
                IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.indentUnit = 2;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: This approach seems to be explicitly discouraged [1] now: 

"Note that you will find legacy extensions on the internet that do not define load_ipython_extension and rely on IPython's Events, and Custom.js. While this does work for the time being, these extensions will break in the future and are subject to race conditions."
[1]:https://carreau.gitbooks.io/jupyter-book/content/notebook-extensions.html

Answer (score 47):

The official documentation has an [example answering this specific question](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frontend_config.html#example-changing-the-notebook-s-default-indentation). This worked for me with IPython 4.

**Summary**: Paste the following into your browser's javascript console

```
var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
var config = cell.config;
var patch = {
      CodeCell:{
        cm_config:{indentUnit:2}
      }
    }
config.update(patch)
```

The setting is persisted. You can [roll back](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frontend_config.html#example-restoring-the-notebook-s-default-indentation) by exchanging `: 2` for `: null`.

Comment: Yes, I have met this, but this totally unacceptable if not outrageous. Jupyter Notebook is the only editor I have met in my life in whuch you cannot set your own TAB space! Besides, it's such a simple and common request!

Comment: To see the changes you also need to reload the notebook page in the browser

Comment: The link in the answer is no longer valid (2022-12)

Answer (score 41):

From the official documentation for CodeMirror Code Cells:

1. Open an Ipython Notebook
2. Create a **Code Cell** e.g. by pressing `b`
3. Open your browser’s JavaScript console and run the following

snippet:

```
var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
var config = cell.config;
var patch = {
      CodeCell:{
        cm_config:{indentUnit:2}
      }
    }
config.update(patch)
```

4. Reload the notebook page in the browser e.g. by pressing `F5`

**This will fix it permanently.** I assume this works only on recent versions, not sure though!

Comment: This procedure works on my Windows 10 Chrome. Jupyter notebook version: 4.2.3. Thank you!

Comment: works as well on MacOS `10.11.6` with Jupyter notebook `5.0.0`

Comment: I did the above, i.e. copy-pasted the code into Firefox browser console, it was accepted but it also issued an error: "ReferenceError: Jupyter is not defined"! Oh comeon, it's already an offbeat solution. It doesn't work either!

Comment: @Apostolos you have to open the Console from the browser tab that is displaying your notebook. You interact with the site that is displayed. See f.e. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Comment: Thanks @Frank for your delayed answer. You talk about learning how to drive. However, the question is very specific: it's how to pull the seat of the car further back. (All this is figurative speaking, of course.) Anyway I have solved the problem since then.

Answer (score 32):

AdamAL's answer is correct. It worked for me.

However it only changes the indentation in the Jupyter Notebook and leaves the indentation in the Jupyter Editor unaffected.

A more direct way to change the indentation is to directly edit the Jupyter config files in the `.jupyter/nbconfig` directory. This directory contains 2 files:

```
edit.json
notebook.json
```

The option you must set in either one is `indentUnit`. Here is the content of my Jupyter config files:

**edit.json:**

```
{
  "Editor": {
    "codemirror_options": {
      "indentUnit": 2,
      "vimMode": false, 
      "keyMap": "default"
    }
  }
}
```

**notebook.json:**

```
{
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "indentUnit": 2
    }
  }
}
```

With this approach I've set the default indentation to 2 in both the Jupyter Notebook and the Jupyter Editor.

Comment: The above configuration files also work for changing indentation to use tab characters. Use "indentWithTabs": true in cm_config and codemirror_options. Other suggestions were either not permanent or didn't work with Jupyter 4.1.1/iPython 5.1.0

Comment: Adding to this response:

   * Configuration directory can be found with `jupyter --config_dir`

   * If the directory and `nbconfig/` and the files `edit.json` and `notebook.json` don't exist, you can create them with the contents described by bpirvu.

Comment: The indentWithTabs option should not be set, as iggie suggests, at least not for python code. It is against widely used convention and it can lead to indentation errors. PEP-8 also believes you should use spaces in python.

Comment: This works for all notebook types, including Node.js. +1

Comment: Thank you for actually showing where are the files of interests!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks @bpirvu !

Comment: This is the best answer here.

Answer (score 13):

If you use **jupyterlab**, there seems to be an easier way:

1) Click jupyterlab menu Settings > Advanced Setting Editor

2) Click "Notebook" on the left hand pane, make sure you are on "Raw View"

3) On the right pane, under "User Overrides", enter this:

```
{
    "codeCellConfig": {
        "tabSize": 2
    }
}
```

If you look at the System Defaults, that will give you hint on whats overridable and you can repeat this for other settings.

I tried this on Google Platform AI Notebook which uses Jupyterlab.

Comment: Feb 22, 2022 - Jupyter-Lab 3.2.4 worked ! Thank goodness.

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is now best wrapped in a event handler to load once per notebook load:

```
$([IPython.events]).on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
  IPython.CodeCell.options_default['cm_config']['indentUnit'] = 2;
});
```

Comment: Even though I'm using juypter this worked for me (added the line at the bottom of  ~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js

Comment: I added this to `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` (after creating the `custom/` dir)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding

`IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.indentUnit = 2;`

to your `custom.js` file as suggested by Jakob, be sure to clear your browser cache as well before restarting ipython notebook!

Also, you may have to first create the `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/static/custom/` directory (use `echo $(ipython locate default)` to find your default directory) before adding the `custom.js` file.