# How to enable line wrapping in ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to enable line wrapping in ipython notebook. I googled it with no results and i typed ipython notebook --help in a terminal. This gives me a ton of configuration commands for a config file, but no line wrapping. Does anyone know if ipnotebook has this feature and if so how to enable it?
Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

As @Matt pointed out you have to configure CodeMirror to enable wrapping.

However, this can be achieved by simply adding the following line to your `custom.js`:

```
 IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineWrapping = true;
```

So there is no need to loop through all the cells.
In a similar fashion you can enable [line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20197471/2870069), set the [indentation depth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19068730/2870069) and so on (see the link posted by @Matt for other options). The location of your `custom.js` depends on your OS (on my Ubuntu machine it is `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom`).

### Update:

In IPython 3 the plain call does not work any more, thus it is required to place the setting within an appropriate event handler. A possible solution could look like:

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace',
    'base/js/events'
    ],
    function(IPython, events) {
        events.on("app_initialized.NotebookApp",
            function () {
                IPython.Cell.options_default.cm_config.lineWrapping = true;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

To implement line wrapping in notebooks in ipython 3, I used [the answer @Jakob linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24615436/1569064) and @Jakob's actual answer.  Using the single line of code did not work in my case - however adding the following to `custom.js` does:

```
$([IPython.events]).on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
  IPython.CodeCell.options_default['cm_config']['lineWrapping'] = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, in case this saves others some time, the custom.js file you need to add the above to is located in python3.?/site-packages/IPython/html/static/custom/.  E.g., on my OS-X 10.10 python3.4 alt-install, it's here: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/static/custom/custom.js.  If you can't find it, use the find utility (e.g., find / -name 'custom.js'), and make sure you're looking at the correct Python tree. :)

Comment: I have an Ipython Notebook that utilizes `custom.css` and the above code doesn't work when input into the `custom.js` file. For some reason code cell text wrapping isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Most of notebook is powered by Codemirror, the option you search is hence [this one](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_lineWrapping) problem is we don't have simple way of passing configuration to CodeMirror, so you will have to figure out some javascript un `custom.js` to apply the configuration to the right object.

From the top of my head and handwaving :I would say `IPython.CodeCell.default_options.cm` les `lineWrapping` to true  then loop through `IPython.notebook.get_cells()` (already instantiated object) grab their `editor` attribute and `setOption('lineWrapping',true)`.

You can make a JS extension that does it and propose (and take inspiration) [here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions).