# How to wrap code/text in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter-notebooks for python coding. Is there a way to wrap text/code in a jupyter notebook code cell?

Picture provided below.

[image: Text not wrapping]

By wrap text means "how text is wrapped in MS-word"

Comment: You could try the answer(s) provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672537/how-to-enable-line-wrapping-in-ipython-notebook). If it works out, you could answer your own question so others who search for this know that it still works in jupyter notebooks

Comment: @M.T : these steps are for Ipython notebook. I came across thread like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/AczTdZqStoM but I am unable to find files like ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using jupyter-lab (rather than jupyter notebook) the solution is much simpler.

You can do:

Settings > Advanced setting Editor > TextEditor > checkbox enable Line Wrap.

[image: Advanced settings editor]

Comment: when the orinal questions was posted, unfortunately back then this want there

Comment: How do you show the "Settings" menu on your Jupyter notebook? I only have these on the menus: `File Edit View Insert Cell Kernel Widgets Help`

Comment: Same for me, no Settings menu. I don't even have Widgets. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: This is Jupyter Lab, it is useful, and most people asking this question should probably use it instead of jupyter notebook, but does not directly answer the question.

Comment: Those working in JupyterLab and looking to wrap text in the cells in the `.ipynb` file and not 'Text Editor' (like I think above is about), will want to see [the discussion here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/15579#issuecomment-1872569381) for where to be looking and trying things in JupyterLab in early 2024.

Answer (score 130):

Find your configuration directory via `jupyter --config-dir` (mine is `~/.jupyter`). Then edit or create `nbconfig/notebook.json` to add the following:

```
{
  "MarkdownCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineWrapping": true
    }
  },
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineWrapping": true
    }
  }
}
```

(If you have something else in it, ensure you have valid JSON with no trailing commas after `}`s.)

Restart Jupyter and reload your notebook.

Source: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/106

Comment: This approach is not working for me.  nbconfig should be a new subdirectory to .jupyter and notebook.json should be a textfile stored in it?

Comment: This didn't work for me either--until I realized the `json` file format doesn't like `#` comments. It's my habit of quoting the source of my edits in config files, such as this post's URL.

Comment: @ J Kelly. That's correct, you can create the `nbconfig` with `mkdir nbconfig`, then `nano notebook.json` to create an empty file named `notebook.json` in which you will paste the code.

Comment: This works. my notebook config file is located at `/home/username/anaconda3/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`

Comment: Extensions were not enabled by default on my system. After enabling them using the command `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`, it is working fine. For more [details](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/186#issuecomment-359049200)

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work in Google colab? I can't find the config file in question.

Comment: If you want to do it directly from the notebook you can use the following 3 lines of code:
`from notebook.services.config import ConfigManager`
`c = ConfigManager()`
`c.update('notebook', {"CodeCell": {"cm_config": {"lineWrapping": True}}})`

Comment: I have two questions:
1) Where do I enter ```jupyter --config-dir```?
2) How do I access the file ```nbconfig/notebook.json```? 

(Sorry for the newbie questions...)

Comment: What about Google Colab? I tried `from notebook.services.config import ConfigManager ...` but it does not take effect.

Comment: Instead of doing both "MarkdownCell" and "CodeCell", I just did "Cell". It's one less thing to worry about.

Answer (score 30):

In addition to Dan's answer, **you can apply line wrapping for all cells** (code or markdown) by specifying the top object as Cell. Adding the code below to your `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`

```
{
  "Cell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineWrapping": true
    }
  }
}
```

Ex: This is my cell config

```
{
  "Cell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineNumbers": false,
      "lineWrapping": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work for me (under Jupyter version 4.2.0), but Dan's answer does.

Comment: @eden, is there a similar option for autowrap width in output cells?

Answer (score 18):

[image]

In VS Code, go to **File > Preferences > Settings > Search "wrap" > check the "Notebook > Output: Word Wrap" box**, as shown in the screenshot

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks.  For others new to VS Code the settings are: File>Preferences>Settings

Answer (score 3):

I am working with Jupyter notebook (*.ipynb*) through VSC Visual Studio Code, and I did find out that setting line/word wrapping could be set as follows:

1. hit `F1`
2. choose *Preferences: Open Settings (UI)*
3. start typing in *wrap*
4. *Editor: **Word Wrap** Controls how lines should wrap* pops up, change to **On**

It works for code (Python cells). Markdown cells work fine even without changing above setting.

Answer (score 3):

if you are running jupyter notebook in vscode, and you want to wrap the output text/code. you can enable word warp in settings:

1. go to command pallet
2. type `@tag:notebookLayout`
3. scoll down and enable word wrap:
   [image]

Comment: This enables word wrap for the the editor but not for the cell output.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest for me was this, straightforward and does not require a pip install:

```
from textwrap import wrap
long_str = 'I rip wrap unravel when I time travel, with beats in my head'
lines = wrap(long_str, 20) #wrap outputs a list of lines
print('\n'.join(lines))    #so join 'em with newline

#prints: 
#I rip wrap unravel
#when I time travel,
#with beats in my
#head
```

Comment: This does not concern directly to how Jupyter Notebook wraps any input as in the question context. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just select cell as markdown, it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But if your cell contains code you need to split the cell into markdown + code

Answer (score 0):

This may not be as satisfactory of an answer but while working Google Colab, I use the three single quote marks above and below the line of comments. Once quote marks are in place, I can hit return where I see fit.

Original comment:

```
# Using the number of rows from the original concatenated dataframe and the trimmed dataframe, quantify the percent difference between the number of rows lost
```

Solution:

'''
Using the number of rows from the original concatenated dataframe and the
trimmed dataframe, quantify the percent difference between the number of
rows lost
'''

Here is a screen grab of the solution:
[image]

Comment: This won't work for the lines of code, moreover the OP never asked for how to split the code in lines using `'\'` or comments using `''' '''`. Rather what he is looking for is to *"wrap"* the content on the cells automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of these solutions worked for me, I opted for a different approach and wrote a simple column-wrapping print function that you can use to manually guarantee that the lines of any string will remain in view, for simple output checking scenarios.

```
def printwr( item, wrapCol=70 ):
    """ wrap printing to column limit """
    posit = 0
    while True:
        # if remaining legnth eq/less than wrapCol, print and rturn
        if len(item[posit:]) <= wrapCol: print(item[posit:]); return
        # else take wrapCol chars from last index
        llim = posit+wrapCol+1
        # if more than one item, drop last contiguous non-space sequence (word)
        lineSpl = item[posit:llim].split(' ')
        segment = ' '.join(lineSpl[:-1]) if len(lineSpl)>1 else lineSpl
        # print segment and increment posit by length segment
        posit += len(segment)+1
        print(segment)
```

For example, for

```
exampleStr = "populations tend to cluster in the foothills and periphery of the rugged Hindu Kush range; smaller groups are found in many of the country's interior valleys; in general, the east is more densely settled, while the south is sparsely populated"

printwr(exampleStr)
```

produces:

> populations tend to cluster in the foothills and periphery of the
> rugged Hindu Kush range; smaller groups are found in many of the
> country's interior valleys; in general, the east is more densely
> settled, while the south is sparsely populated

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p $(jupyter --config-dir)/nbconfig && nano $(jupyter --config-dir)/nbconfig/notebook.json
```

Copy and Paste it in your terminal. It will open the Configuration file directly.

Then paste this or append this in the file -

```
{
  "MarkdownCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineWrapping": true
    }
  },
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineWrapping": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

## Shortest Answer Ever

Try adding a ' \ ' in between the lines of code you need to split.

This allows you to split your code over different lines and helps it look prettier.

Comment: This requires user to makes change to code (insert '\'). A better solution (if any) would let the tool (jupyter) handle it.