# How do you wrap lines in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, word-wrap

I have a Jupyter notebook that I wish to convert to pdf for publication, however when I save the notebook as a pdf many of the cells go over the edge.

Is there are way to wrap lines (to the standard 80 characters) so that as I type the cells are never wider than a standard A4 page?

Alternatively, is there something I can do when I convert to pdf instead?
Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419342/how-to-wrap-code-text-in-jupyter-notebooks

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/392

Comment: @Roelant thanks for the link, however these line wraps do not persist when the notebook is converted to pdf. Do you know any way of making them remain?

Comment: See https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/323 tl;dr, either ensure your lines are short enough in your notebook, or use a custom post-processor to break lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which will always wrap long lines (not just on export to psd):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39398949/5411817

Essentially, there is a flag in Jupyter's config file which turns on line wrapping.

Simply add the following to your config:

```
{
  "MarkdownCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineWrapping": true
    }
  },
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineWrapping": true
    }
  }
}
```

You'll need to **restart Jupyter** to see the change.

You can find (or create) your config file in your user directory: `~/.ipython/profile_nbserver/ipython_notebook_config.py`,

```
-
```

**My Bad: I did not realize that line wrapping breaks on export to PDF !!**
Comment under question by @Louie links to a discussion and [sample code for writing a custom exporter](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/323#issuecomment-274149682).  He also poses a workaround of manually wrapping long lines (in a pinch).

I'll leave my answer here, as it answers the question posted as the Title ("**How do you wrap lines in a Jupiter Notebook?**"), and highlights that the usual solution breaks on pdf export. Others looking for that answer can easily find it in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved in [nbconvert 5.5](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html?highlight=latex#id2) Just update and run

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf your-notebook.ipynb
```

Comment: I'm still facing this issue, so this may not be resolved yet.