# how to toggle linewrap in jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, toggle

It seems possible to wrap long lines with some customization of jupyter as described here [How to wrap code/text in Jupyter notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419342/how-to-wrap-code-text-in-jupyter-notebooks) but can I get something not permanent? I want something I can toggle on and off depending on the need on the particular cell, possibly via a keyboard shortcut ... is there anything?