# Automatic Adjustment of Cell Width

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Typically if a line of a code is too long, you have to horizontally scroll to see the whole thing. I adjust my window size constantly so I would prefer to see long lines move to the next lines automatically without having to manually edit this.

I've seen this is possible with Jupyter but haven't found a way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Correct terminology is "wrapping". I found the solution here.

[How to wrap code/text in Jupyter notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419342/how-to-wrap-code-text-in-jupyter-notebooks#)