# How to stop overflowing code in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have to work on Jupyter Notebook and I'm dealing with overflowing code.
There's already a topic on it: [How to wrap code/text in Jupyter notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419342/how-to-wrap-code-text-in-jupyter-notebooks)
But the thing is I don't have nbconfig/notebook.json in ~/.jupyter.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbbZE.png)

All I have in it are 2 directories "lab" and "labconfig" and one file "migrated". "Lab" leads to several other directories until I fall on a file called "browser.jupyterlab-setting" and there's a file called "page.config.json" in "labconfig" in which I tried to copy/paste the code that I've found on the topic I mentioned. But it didn't work. I also create "nbconfig/notebook.json" directly in ~/.jupyter and again copy paste the code that should solve my problem. But, when I restart jupyter notebook, the problem is still there. I fear to do something wrong if I keep on doing anything.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what' the output of `jupyter --config-dir`?

Comment: Possibly not what you're looking for, but I'd break up that logical line into several physical lines

Comment: It may be important here to add what version of Jupyter Notebook you are using? Currently Jupyter Notebook 7+ is out and built on enitrely different tech than 6.4 and earlier and NbClassic. Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on JupyterLab tech and so approaches that work with JupyterLab are needed for newer versions. This may be why you are seeing discrepancies with posted solutions and your attempts. I cannot be sure though, not knowing.

Comment: @PaulH 
jupyter --config -dir returns /home/myname/.jupyter

Comment: @Wayne  the version I'm using is 7.1.1

Comment: Yes, so the post you reference [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36419342/8508004) and the top answer to it, both date to **2016**. Jupyter Notebook 7+ is fairly new as [it just premiered July **2023**](https://blog.jupyter.org/announcing-jupyter-notebook-7-8d6d66126dcf) and is built on JupyterLab components. Hence, **usually** often you'll want to search for how to do things in current versions of JupyterLab now as they are more applicable to how to do things in Jupyter Notebook 7+ than posts dating to 2016. So far, for this case that doesn't seem to hold. I haven't located the 'trick' ...

Comment: <continued>  to this yet. Or at least how to demonstrate it. [This is the way in JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/15579#issuecomment-1878802473); however, in [the current demo of Jn 7.1](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/83b0b625cb3b6e05d7f3d8714f98182e), I don't see a different equivalent there. It's possible I just haven't found the right place yet. (The time [I looked into it a few days ago](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/text-wrapping-in-notebook/24228/2?u=fomightez), the question wasn't about an active notebook coding experience & so it didn't get resolved.)