# Why are some variables and comments in my IPython notebook red?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Is this a syntax highlighting issue in my iPython notebook?  Can I remove it?  This happens in some of my cells, but not others.

[image: ipython red text]

I'm viewing [this iPython notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/2_fullyconnected.ipynb).

Comment: Certainly looks like a syntax highlighting issue. The javascript parser might be messed-up. That's the only reason I can think of. Not sure what you are looking for as far as an answer goes...

Comment: I'm not familiar with how iPython notebooks handle syntax highlighting -- how is a js parser involved?  I see nothing in my juypter config related to syntax highlighting.  Answers could point out why this is happening or how to futz with the syntax highlighter.

Comment: iPython (now Jupyter) notebooks run with a Tornado (a Python framework) web-server. The HTML and CSS are doing the display stuff, but the dynamic syntax highlighting is all ran by Javascript.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is because the indentation is screwed up. 
For consistency the codemirror parser will make a red line if it's not indented 4 spaces (or if it's indented with tabs, depending on codemirror version). The parser has some edge case that indeed highlight only a few of theses lines in red, I won't go into details, but if you indent 4 spaces it will work.

You can either:

- select the block of code and press `tab`
- use `alt`-`click'n'drag` vertically to place multiple cursors in front of your code, and press space enough time to make the correct indent 4 space.

Setting the indent to 2 is possible, but complex and not recommended. 4 space is the python norm.

Comment: I'm building off of notebooks that use the 2-space convention, so I ended up changing the indent via [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24615436/232638).

Comment: That's a bad thing to do. You better have to convert the notebook to use 4 tabs. Notebook files are json so easy to process.

Answer (score 2):

This is the official solution from the [Jupyter Notebook documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frontend_config.html#example-changing-the-notebook-s-default-indentation):

1. Open a Jupyter Notebook
2. Select a **Code Cell**
3. Open your browser's JavaScript console and run the following snippet:

   ```
   var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
   var config = cell.config;
   var patch = {
         CodeCell:{
           cm_config:{indentUnit:2}
         }
       }
   config.update(patch)
   ```
4. Reload the Notebook page

**This fix is permanent.**

To reverse the change repeat the process running this snippet:

```
var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
var config = cell.config;
var patch = {
      CodeCell:{
        cm_config:{indentUnit: null} # only change here.
      }
    }
config.update(patch)
```