# How can I configure indentation size in my Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'd like to have a default indentation size of 2 spaces instead of 4 spaces in my Jupyter notebooks. How can I do this?

Note: this is not a duplicate of [How do I change the autoindent to 2 space in IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068730/how-do-i-change-the-autoindent-to-2-space-in-ipython-notebook), as that question is for (deprecated) IPython notebooks and not (current) Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way to do this is in bpirvu's buried answer to [How do I change the autoindent to 2 space in IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068730/how-do-i-change-the-autoindent-to-2-space-in-ipython-notebook):

Just edit `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json`. Here is a complete `notebook.json` which includes the relevant setting:

```
{
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "indentUnit": 2
    }
  }
}
```

There's also a more hacky solution that's more prevalent around the web, probably because the Jupyter documentation is lacking on this topic and `indentUnit` is only mentioned here: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frontend_config.html. This solution is to open your browser's JavaScript console and enter

```
var cell = Jupyter.notebook.get_selected_cell();
var config = cell.config;
var patch = {
      CodeCell:{
        cm_config:{indentUnit:2}
      }
    }
config.update(patch)
```

which ends up editing `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json` for you.

Comment: Trying the second console solution produced the following error for me: `Uncaught TypeError: config.update is not a function; at <anonymous>:8:8;`. Meh.

Comment: This doesn't change the auto indent length. For example, if I hit enter after typing `for i in range(10) :`, I get 4 spaces instead of 2.